# How to prevent htaccess from redirecting non-www urls except those that begin with certain strings?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using the drupal htaccess suggested redirection code because i want my webpage to be browsed with the www prefix only. The bad thing about this is that, apparently, `stats.domainname.tld` gets redirected to `www.stats.domainname.tld` which is not wanted.

How to change the following htaccess rewrite rule to not do that?

```
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: is there any disadvantage of doing it like this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|stats)\. [NC]`

Comment: No real disadvantage but if you setup another subdomain tomorrow calling it `sub1.domainname.tld` that you want to exclude then again you will have to update this rule to: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|stats|sub1)\. [NC] `